# CSS - Align dynamically created drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to align the two drop down boxes in the following image:

[image]

Javascript (for 1st drop down box)

```
//create drop-down box
            var s = $('<select/>',{id:"category"});
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                $('<option/>', {value: value.category, text: value.category}).appendTo(s);

            });     

            // add the category drop-down box.
            s.appendTo('#categories');
```

CSS:

```
#category
{   
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;
display:block;
}

#categories
{   
font-family: 'underdogregular';
padding: 0px; 
margin: 0px auto;
text-align:center;
width: 280px;       
}
```

HTML:

```
<body >

    <div id='categories'>
        <h3 id ='couponCategoriesTitle'>Coupon Categories</h3>          
     </div>

    <div id = 'categorySubmitButtonDiv' >
        <!--Add Category Search Button-->
        <button class = "buttons" onclick="categorySubmit()">Search!</button>
    </div>      

</body>
```

I've only copied over the parts that I thought were relevant.

Would anyone know how I can get the two text boxes aligned in the middle?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: best way is set width and height of that div then your css will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the little code to your body

**code:**

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyFey/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
<div id="subCategory">
    <div>categories</div>
    <div>
<select >
    <option>lorem 1</option>
       <option>lorem 2</option>   
</select>
    </div>
    <input type="button"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#subCategory{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bjyQk/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center your text inside your dropdowns, I think of two possibilities:

- using text-indent and tweaking values, but this will work just for
  the selected option (the one visible), and it's not so reliable;
- making a custom dropdown, using an ul list and li items (for istance,
  or any other tags you like) and writing your custom logic for
  showing/hiding list of items; this way text-align: center will work
  fine for all items;
- using a [plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo) that could be tweaked with text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your entire input field area on a div with `text-align:center;`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joelworsham/3mU7Y/) (Containing div has border just so you can better see what's happening)